# MiKTeX, TeXnicCenter and "cancel" package - errors

Tags: miktex, texniccenter, cancel

**EDIT2:**
I answered it below. I had duplicate of my cancel.sty where my .tex file was. That made some troubles (obviously).

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}\cancel{a}
\end{document}
```

I went to MiKTeX Package Manager, found "cancel" package, right click -> Install. Refreshed FNDB. Opened TeXnicCenter, wrote that code and tried to render it. I got 16 errors. Why (for me "normal" LaTeX, packages like **amsmath** are working and I'm able it to render it just fine, but now I need some additional functionality like this strikethrough in cancel package)?

```
MiKTeX 2.9
TeXnicCenter 1.0 RC1
- rendered via Sumatra PDF
```

[image]

Comment: After installation, you need to refresh your FNDB (filename database). See [How do I refresh the file name database?](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/maintenance.html#refreshfndb). From the command prompt, type `initexmf --update-fndb` or click "Refresh FNDB" from the MiKTeX start menu. Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I did. But still the same.

Comment: Use `$\cancel{a}$`. Does this work?

Comment: No, 48 errors (before "only" 16).

Comment: Does it work if you write something before `\cancel{a}`, or if you put it in mathmode? Your example didn't work for me either, unless I did one of those things.

Comment: I got some output with $\cancel{n^2}$ but with 48 errors :/ (see above)

Comment: If I put something before still no proper output but with less errors, 12 - starting from "Missing = inserted for \ifdim"

Comment: I've closed as 'too localized' as this is basically an issue to do with having an old, out-of-date version of a package 'hanging about'.

Answer (score 2):

The [`cancel` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) description states:

> A package to draw diagonal lines ("cancelling" a term) and arrows with
>   limits (cancelling a term "to a value") through parts of maths
>   formulae.

As such using `$\cancel{a}$` should work. For this to work after installing the `cancel` package, you need to update your FNDB (filename database) first (See [How do I refresh the file name database?](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/maintenance.html#refreshfndb)).

This may be an isolated case since the use of `\cancel{a}` as the first element in a document (or paragraph) is unlikely in general and therefore particular to this test case. Prepending `\cancel` with anything is sufficient to remove the error.

Comment: Actually, `\cancel` should work in text mode as well (see the manual).

Comment: I got the output but with 48 errors (see above) :/

Comment: A minimal example with *only* `$\cancel{a}$` worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\cancel` on the very first word. It works for me, if I begin with a character or just `\mbox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}\cancel{a}
\end{document}
```

If I use `\cancel` at the beginning of a paragraph, as in your example, I can confirm there's an error:

```
! You can't use `\/' in vertical mode.
\@cancel ...ht \unitlength \p@ \canc@thinlines {\/
                                                  \raise \dimen@ \hbox {\ooa...
l.7 \cancel{a}
```

Comment: Still not working, no proper output and errors all around. See first post (updated).

Comment: @svebee As your screenshot shows, you work with `cancel.sty` on your desktop, not with the MiKTeX installed `cancel`. Remove `cancel.sty` from your desktop and delete the `testCancel.aux` file, then try again.

Comment: Yeah, I realized it (put it as answer already). Thanks :)

Comment: Final note for readers, the answer solved the initial problem, the error message in the question has bee edited, removed, replaced by another screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the thing was I had copy of my **cancel.sty** on my desktop where was my source **.tex** file. When I deleted (.sty file) it - everything is working just fine :) As user **Werner** says

> TeX searches the local folder first before examining the FNDB for
>   packages/document classes. As such, the older copy of cancel was used
>   instead of the updated/installed newer version, causing the error.
>   Once the local copy was removed, the updated style file could be
>   accessed, solving the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can reword your answer into a more general form so that it helps others as well. Something like "TeX searches the local folder first before examining the FNDB for packages/document classes. As such, the older copy of `cancel` was used *instead of* the updated/installed newer version, causing the error. Once the local copy was removed, the updated style file could be accessed, solving the problem."